# Different number of digits in PI

Tags: python, variables, printing, pi

I am a beginner in Python and I have a doubt regarding PI.

```
>>> import math
>>> p = math.pi
>>> print p
3.14159265359
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
```

- Why are the two having different number of digits ?
- How can I get the value of Pi up to more decimal places without using the Chudnovsky algorithm?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, just post the code itself

Comment: @TimCastelijns I thought my question would look a bit more authentic if I added a picture of the terminal.

Comment: You could enter anything in a text editor and take a screen shot of that; it wouldn't make the code more authentic than just directly copy-pasting the results from the Python terminal. There is a code-block option when editing your question just for that. The big advantage of copy-paste the text and keeping it (HTML) text in your question, is that other people can copy-paste your code for testing; you can't (easily) copy-paste  code from a picture.

Comment: @Evert Thanks for the advice. I will keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: FWIW, my code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26478803/4014959) can compute large numbers of pi digits using the Decimal module. It uses the Salamin / Brent / Gauss Arithmetic-Geometric Mean formula, so it converges rather quickly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why are the two having different number of digits ?

One is 'calculated' with `__str__`, the other with `__repr__`:

```
>>> print repr(math.pi)
3.141592653589793
>>> print str(math.pi)
3.14159265359
```

`print` uses the return value of `__str__` of objects to determine what to print. Just doing `math.pi` uses `__repr__`.

> How can I get the value of Pi up to more decimal places without using Chudnovsky algorithm ?

You can show more numbers with `format()` like so

```
>>> print "pi is {:.20f}".format(math.pi)
pi is 3.14159265358979311600
```

Where 20 is the number of decimals. More info in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Note that after 48 decimals Python will just print zeros if you ask for more places.

Comment: Also note that this value of pi is accurate only up to the 15th decimal place.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thank you. I had absolutely forgotten about the `str()` and `repr()`.

Comment: @ajcr I could not agree more with you. Do you have a better solution ?

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi: floats can't be relied upon to hold more accurate approximations of pi in their lower-order bits, so a possible next step is to use Python's `Decimal` class to hold the number. This gives you arbitrary finite accuracy, but at the cost of memory and calculation speed. It really depends on what your further requirements are.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi: As mentioned in Wikipedia's article on [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), with _some_ values you get 17 decimal digits of precision, but in general you shouldn't rely on more than 15 digits.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan can you explain why is it restricted to just 48 decimal places? I reckon there must be some memory constraint for this to happen but I am just curious to know the actual reason

Answer (score 3):

The `print` function rounds off the float to some extent. You can change how much, using:

```
print "%1.<number>f" % math.pi
```

In this particular case:

```
print "%1.11f" % math.pi
```