# looping over product to compute a serie in python

Tags: python

I'm just gonna compute the result of below serie in python:

The formula

[image]

So, here is my function to compute:

```
 def compute(limit):
     pi = 1
     for i in range(1,limit):
         pi = pi * ((4*(i**2))//(4*(i**2)-1))
     print(2*pi)

 compute(10000) /*returns 2*/
```

I know it is a silly question. But could you address the problem with this snippet?

Comment: If you'd like a series that converges _much_ more rapidly, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26478803/4014959

Answer (score 0):

Change one of the 4s into a float by putting a . after it and change the // into /. It makes python interpret everything as floats:

```
def compute(limit):
    pi = 1
    for i in range(1,limit):
        pi = pi * ((4.*(i**2))/(4*(i**2)-1))
    print(2*pi)

compute(10000)
```

Comment: Great... your kindness.

Comment: You don't need to make a 4 into a float in Python 3, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I still use python 2.7.x, but indeed, in python 3 you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, `//` is integer division. No matter whether you're dividing floats or integers, the result will always be an integer. Pi is not an integer, so you should use float division: `/` and tell Python explicitly that you really want a float by converting one of the numbers to float<sup>*</sup>. For example, you could do `4` -> `4.` (notice the dot).

You could do the same thing in a more clear way using [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) and [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) modules and a generator expression.

```
import functools 
import operator

def compute(limit):
    return 2 * functools.reduce(operator.mul, ((4.*(i**2)/(4*(i**2)-1) for i in range(1, limit + 1))
```

<sub>* Python 3 does float division with `4/(something)` even without this, but Python 2.7 will need `from __future__ import division` to divide as freely as Python 3, otherwise the division will result in an integer in any way.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

You have `//` and not `/`, you wanted division, but made floor division

```
def compute(limit):
    pi = 1
    for i in range(1,limit):
        pi = pi * ((4*(i**2))/(4*(i**2)-1))  # you had here //
    print(2*pi)

compute(10000)
```

Output:

```
3.1415141108281714
```