# Python, How long decimal point can a float have?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a pi calculator. But it just corrects first 7 decimal points and starts returning the same results. By the look of the things it is about my float values getting bigger because I use a limit. But is there a limit for decimal numbers in python? I read some documents but there are numbers with even 100 decimal points but I can just get to 11.

My code:

```
import math
import decimal
import datetime

sqrtt=1.
sumn=0.
tryc=0
outerrepeat=1000000000
while outerrepeat>0:
    tryc+=1
    repeat=10000000
    a=datetime.datetime.now()
    print "\n>>>Processing...\n"
    while repeat>0:

        sumn+=1/(sqrtt**2)
        sqrtt+=1
        repeat-=1
    b=datetime.datetime.now()
    print ">>>Process complete.\n"
    print ">>>Calculate time: "+str(b-a) + " Try-" + str(tryc) +" "+      str(math.sqrt(sumn*6)) + "\n"
    outerrepeat-=1


print "\nThis is all I can do."
```

May help: Running on IDLE. Calculation is done by basel problem. Always gets stuck at 3.14159264498. Also never gets further than 11 decimal points but sometimes gets lower. Should say that my limit (sqrtt) hits 8th power of 10 (Maybe lower but higher than 7th power of 10.)
Thanks.

Comment: This famous series takes a long time to converge; there are _much_ faster ways to calculate pi. But why aren't you using the `decimal` module you imported? It can calculate square roots to as many places as you want (assuming you have enough RAM).

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26478803/4014959) is some Python 2 code I wrote a while ago that calculates pi to high precision, using the decimal module. It can do 1000 decimal places in under a second.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the op answer but that's more than I can take as a junior. :D

Comment: Hey, don't worry, I don't know why that algorithm works, either. :) But the code itself shouldn't be too hard to understand if you go through it slowly.

Comment: Not the code the algorithm, I'm just in highschool.

Comment: Also found a thing to mees up with whole week, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also very useful will be this tutorial.
[Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

The precision of python floats is bordered to 17 digits. 
"On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision available for a Python float". Its not only python, it is a standart. So it is useful to be familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

With a typical python implementation, floats are 64 bits, with 53 bits of precision. That's 15 to 17 significant decimal digits.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Thanks and what about integers?

Comment: Having said that the print also trim some of the precision -
```>>> math.sqrt(sumn*6)
3.1415925580959025
>>> str(math.sqrt(sumn*6))
'3.1415925581'```

Comment: @ElvezTheElf integers have a precision of 1 by definition.

Comment: Integers in current versions of python don't have a fixed limit of digits. Python will allocate enough bytes of memory to store your integer until you run out of ram.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses 64 bit floats which have [15 to 17 decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) of precision.

Proof can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/floatobject.h) where we can see the python `float` value is stored as a C double (which is almost always a 64 bit floating point number).

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    double ob_fval;  // this is the actual float value
} PyFloatObject;
```

---

You can use the [decimal.Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) object for infinite precision.

An example with calculating [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

```
import decimal
import math

decimal.getcontext().prec = 100  # set the precision, can be as large as you like

e = decimal.Decimal(0)
next_e = decimal.Decimal('NaN')  # init as not a number
i = 0

while e != next_e:
    e, next_e = next_e, e + decimal.Decimal(1) / math.factorial(i)
    i += 1


e #--> Decimal('2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166428')
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give an examle? Like for my code. I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: There's no such thing as infinite precision. Decimal have _fixed_ precision. That's reason for using them.

Comment: @HåkenLid Of course there is, from the docs: "Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be **as large as needed** for a given problem:"

Comment: You have to specify a fixed precision. It can be much, much larger than 28, but you can't have "infinite" precision. That's not possible, since it would require a computer with infinite memory.

Comment: But that's a hardware limitation, not a software limitation. It's the same way we describe python 3 ints (python 2 longs) as having infinite size. This is very common in computer science.

Comment: On my Pythons (both 2 and 3), floats use 24 bytes of memory as measured by `sys.getsizeof()`. They also appear to provide considerably more that 17 decimal digits of precision. You can see that by converting your program to use floats rather than Decimals and then printing the final result: `print('{:.60f}'.format(e))`.

Comment: Thanks @FHTMitchell, I think I understood.

Comment: @Fmc Nope, they use C doubles. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/floatobject.h . `sys.getsizeof` doesn't show you the size of the float *value*, it's the size of the float object (which includes the `Py_Object_HEAD` info). The `format` method may show more decimal points, but it isn't adding precision, it's a leftover from converting binary to decimal.

Comment: @FHTMitchell It works but how I'm gonna display this value with 100 digits. It still displays just 11

Comment: Figured it out, as @Joe mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @ElvezTheElf No, that's wrong. It will not give you the correct value beyond a certain precision. If you have a `Decimal`  object calling `print decimal_object` will print out to all the correct digits (100 in my example). I think you haven't used `Decimal` objects correctly.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Late but good to answer. I read whole bunch of docs about floating point and You seem to be right. Now my code works more accurate. Thx