# Unable to print after 1076 digits using decimal data type

Tags: python

I wrote a Python program to print n digits of pi after the decimal place using decimal data type. The algorithm I used was the [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula).

The program prints up to 1076 total digits and stops printing no matter what the given precision limit is.

```
from decimal import *    

def nthdigit(n):
    final = 0    

    for k in range(0,n):
        calc =Decimal((16**-k)*(4/(8*k+1) - 2/(8*k+4) - 1/(8*k+5) - 1/(8*k+6)))
        #THE BAILEY-BORWEIN-PLOUFFE FORMULA
        final = Decimal(final+calc)

    print(final)    

n=100000
n=n+1
getcontext().prec = n
nthdigit(n)
```

I was wondering if it was a default setting in the `Decimal` datatype, and if so is there a way to go past that precision limit??

Comment: do you get an error or program completes execution?

Comment: You aren't using `Decimal` to perform your calculations. You're using float, and then converting the resulting float to `Decimal`.

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26478803/4014959) is some Python 2 code I wrote a few years ago that computes pi using the [Salamin / Brent / Gauss Arithmetic-Geometric Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm) formula. Yes, it's a different algorithm, but it shows the proper way to do calculations using `Decimal`.

Comment: Because it uses floats, the only correct digits of pi that your program produces are 3.1415926535897932.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using Decimal to perform your calculations. You're using float, and then converting the resulting float to Decimal.

You don't need to explicitly convert all numbers to Decimal, but at least one number in the innermost parts of your calculations must be Decimal. The Decimal class will convert other numbers as required when you try to do arithmetic with a Decimal and a non-Decimal. To ensure you don't get floating-point errors you should not mix floats and Decimals, *only* combine Decimals with each other, or with integers.

Here's a repaired version of your program.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

def nthdigit(n):
    final = 0
    for k in range(n):
        k = Decimal(k)
        # The Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe Formula
        calc = (4/(8*k+1) - 2/(8*k+4) - 1/(8*k+5) - 1/(8*k+6)) / (16**k)
        final += calc

    return final

n = 1000
n += 1
getcontext().prec = n
print(nthdigit(n))
```

I've wrapped this output to make it easier to read. All of the digits are correct.

> 3. 141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406
>      286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359
>      408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933
>      446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607
>      260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360
>      011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381
>      932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833
>      673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176
>      752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178
>      721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960
>      864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816
>      096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838
>      752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353
>      7875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989